# Django ORM verification of a row in the database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

In my site, the buyer search for a product and once he found it he can contact the seller by pressing on a contact button. If the conversation between the two concerning this product exists he should be redirected to the existing conversation, else, we create a new conversation.
The conversation is hence defined by two users and a listing.
When I try to implement the logic, I am not able to verify both conditions of the existance of the conversation, if the listing exists OR the users exists Django returns that the conversation exists. Here is my code:

```
def create_conversation(request, user_pk1, user_pk2, results_pk):
    user1 = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=user_pk1)
    user2 = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=user_pk2)
    results= get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=results_pk)
    existing_conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(users__in=[user1, user2]).filter(listing=results).values_list('id', flat=True)


    if existing_conversation.exists():

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('conversation:conversation_update', kwargs={'pk':existing_conversation[0]}))
    else:
        conv=Conversation()
        conv.save()
        conv.listing = results
        conv.save()
        conv.users.add(*[user1,user2])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('conversation:conversation_update', kwargs={'pk': conv.pk}))
```

Here is the model of the conversation:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    """
    Model to contain different messages between one or more users.

    :users: Users participating in this conversation.
    :archived_by: List of participants, who archived this conversation.
    :notified: List of participants, who have received an email notification.
    :unread_by: List of participants, who haven't read this conversation.]\['
    listing: the listing the conversation is about.
    read_by_all: Date all participants have marked this conversation as read.

    """
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_('Users'),
        related_name='conversations',
    )
# review the listing before going online, because it is necessary to have a conversation listing
    listing = models.ForeignKey (
        Listing,
        verbose_name=_('Listing'),
        related_name='listing',
        default= 1,
    )
```

and the model of the listing:

class Listing(models.Model):

```
seller = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='seller_listing', verbose_name='sellr', limit_choices_to={'is_seller': True})
    location_Country = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name=_('from_Country'))
    location_State = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name=_('from_State'), null=True, blank=True)
    location_City = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name=_('from_City'))
```

I also tried an approach of divinding it into two conditions: a = conversation.objects.filter(users) and b= conversation.objects.filter(listing), then use if a and b then the conversation exists but got the same issue.

and existing_conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(users__in=[user1, user2]) & Q(listing=results)).values_list('id', flat=True) but got the same issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`intersection()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union) method of django, added since **Django 1.11**, operator to return the shared elements of two or more QuerySets or the bitwise operation `AND` used with the sign `& to get the same behavior.

So in your case, check whether there's an intersection between the two users with `&` or `intersection()`

```
existing_conversation = (user1.conversations.all() & user2.conversations.all()).filter(listing=results)

# or with django intersection

existing_conversation = (user1.conversations.all().intersection(user2.conversations.all())).filter(listing=results)

if existing_conversation.exists():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('conversation:conversation_update', 
       kwargs={'pk':existing_conversation.first().pk}))

 else:
    # rest of the code
```

> BONUS, I see a typo in your code, you didn't send the pk as argument:

```
kwargs={'pk':existing_conversation[0]}
```

get the first instance with `first()` and get the `pk`

```
kwargs={'pk':existing_conversation.first().pk}
```

or

```
kwargs={'pk':existing_conversation[0].pk}
```

Comment: thank you for the approach, but how can I also include the listing? should I use existing conversation user1.conversation.all() & user2.conversations.all() &listing ?

Comment: what is listing? is it a same queryset ?

Comment: you can use intersection only between same Model Queryset, how it supposes to find shared instances if we use different queryset come from different Model

Comment: sorry listing is the result.pk in the result I have the listing the users should talk about.

Comment: what you can is: use filter(), let me update my answer

Comment: In the model I have users and listing, so I need to check these two model fields. existing_conversation = user1.conversations.all() & user2.conversations.all() & listing.conversation.all() ?

Comment: updated my answer, I suppose that you want to check with this `results= get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=results_pk)`

Comment: Let me try it and get back to you, and thank you for the Bonus :)

Comment: I am getting: unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.queryset', should I import something in the view?

Comment: it is bizarre, when debugging using intersect, I got the error mentioned above, when I used & it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: which django version that you use? the intersection has been implemented since Django 1.11

Comment: I am on 1.11.7, but since "&" works i will go with it. Is it a bad practice to use it?